# Finding the upper bound for a number's factors length

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, factoring, cryptography, prime-factorization

Okay, so the title is a bit misleading but I had to keep it short.. Anyhow, if I have a number X what will the length of it's longest two factors be?

For example:

$X = 10000$

I want $3$ and $3$ (as in $100 \cdot 100$) not $4$ and $2$ (as in $1000 \cdot 10$). Is there a way to calculate these lengths without calculating the factors themselves? I need these lengths because I have found a way to factorise huge numbers very efficiently but my algorithm requires these lengths to calculate the factors..

Comment: Do you need actual lengths, or do you need upper bounds on the lengths? The naive upper bound is half the number of digits plus 1. So $10000$ has $5$ digits. $5+1 =6$. So the naive bound is $6/2 = 3$ digits. Getting the actual lengths is as hard as factoring.

Comment: @mixedmath If I use the bounds I need to know another thing: can a composite number have more than two factors of the same length?

Comment: We have $576=24\times 24=12\times 48=16\times 36=18\times 32$.

Comment: Sure. $600 = 30 \cdot 20 = 40 \cdot 15$, for instance.

Comment: @mixedmath But, theoretically in larger numbers this should be rarer right?

Comment: @RandomUser: It doesn't happen if the composite number has exactly two prime factors, e.g. an RSA modulus. (Unless the factors have the same length and you consider $a\times b$ and $b\times a$ different factorizations).

Comment: @HenningMakholm and mixedmath Thank you for your help!

Comment: How's the algorithm work?

Comment: @mixedmath I'm obviously no mathematician, but I am a decent programmer - I am using numerous programming techniques that help me close the gap between factorising 32 bit numbers and 2048 bit numbers. The most important one requires the lengths..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a general way to find the length without also find the factors, but don't that stop you. If you have a "very efficient" algorithm to answer questions like

> What are the two primes with 232 and 269 digits whose product is such-and-such?

then you can factor 500-digit semiprimes fast *in general* -- just run your algorithm 250 times in parallel, trying all the possible combinations of lengths the factors can have.

A 250-fold increase in running time is nothing compared to the gap between "very efficient" and the currently best known factoring algorithms, so you'll be famous either way.

Comment: By very efficient I mean for a 2048 bit number I knew the factors of (and obviously their lengths) it takes roughly 240 hours (sometimes ~80 hours and others ~340 hours) but the algorithm doesn't exactly operate like that.. Most of the calculation is on the length which is used as a variable in the calculation. It would take tens of thousands of hours without the length..

Comment: @RandomUser: Sure, so if you buy 2048 computers and let each of them crunch on the number for ~400 hours, based on different assumptions about the lengths, then one of them will hit the right answer. That's still a _huge_ improvement over any currently known method.

Comment: I meant 240 hours. That's ten days not one. Btw: I would probably be *infamous* for cracking RSA ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Henning Makholm said, there is no general way to find the size of the factors. Indeed, if it were possible to efficiently extract this information to an arbitrary base, it would be possible to reconstruct the factorization in at most a logarithmic number of queries, so this does not appear likely.

To address your claim of an efficient factoring algorithm given this information, I generated random primes with 300 and 317 digits, respectively, such that their product is this 2048-bit number:

> 21279219566254389308166752547567079894155956724663643608660601467894020997654033512063689142868924580279170320271764614879149713751942503658236686096505477139658747642151065213255234834719734092972960617101404366463757484189231718609007575411830503373062342932764298718391072364527123399519860588923934793023541272997882036513859823770256253927113052490646103353524325569726232043935667333299610202485174897340342883688686610744742445811839581892399399720031995216701440209212303269668588156416060110246881815214741950035093818290970782678137302765577041903045627809929443937883795428741882814884536260362427317965217

If you are able to factor this number, I would be happy to publicize your algorithm for you, providing testimony that the number was generated randomly and that I did not share its factorization. Of course, you may prefer to factor RSA-2048:

> 25195908475657893494027183240048398571429282126204032027777137836043662020707595556264018525880784406918290641249515082189298559149176184502808489120072844992687392807287776735971418347270261896375014971824691165077613379859095700097330459748808428401797429100642458691817195118746121515172654632282216869987549182422433637259085141865462043576798423387184774447920739934236584823824281198163815010674810451660377306056201619676256133844143603833904414952634432190114657544454178424020924616515723350778707749817125772467962926386356373289912154831438167899885040445364023527381951378636564391212010397122822120720357

which is widely known to be generated properly, but the size of its factors is unknown. Probably it's either a 309-digit number times a 309-digit number, but it may be a 308-digit number times a 309- or 310-digit number or even something else.

Comment: See, this is the problem. If I am not *certain* about the length of the numbers, I will probably never find the factors.. One digit +- makes the algorithm useless. Edit: I just noticed, you have given lengths for the first one.. I'll get back to you in a month or two ;)

Comment: @RandomUser: That's why I provided you with the first number, which has prime factors of length 300 and 317 digits. If you can factor this number in 10 days (or even 100), you'll have a solid proof that your algorithm works (and I'd be happy to get your name out to the mathematicians & companies that would care).

Comment: And if the computing power is an issue, it should only be a few dollars on EC2 ($4 at current spot prices).

Comment: I can't do the RSA one for reasons I have previously mentioned, but I will try the other number..

Comment: @RandomUser: Good luck! Please let me know of the results, either here or at randomuser@crg4.com.